# Using MySQL in C# on Windows Phone via PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a C# application for a school project and i basicaly need to make basic database operations (mostly inserts),my teacher recomended me to make my C# aplication on WP to call a PHP file to do the operations on my server database.My question is how i get to call the php and send parameters to it via C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SOAP web service using any technology which supports it (in your case I recommend C# if you're not limited to PHP).

Here is some tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

Saying simply, it lets you write some C# functions on the server side (accessing the database in your case) and run them over the Internet from another C# program. The Web service framework handles all magic - you call a function on one side, it gets executed on the other side and result objects are sent back.

As long as you create a SOAP web service on the server side, it's up to you if you write it in Java, C#, PHP, or whatever you like. Available functions will be recognized on the WP side automatically and you will be able to use them like C# functions.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the way but one thing that i notice is that you cant add a web service in vs2012 you only can add a service reference and i cant find a way to instance that

Comment: Newer versions of .NET tend to use WCF services instead of old good ASP.NET web services (which are still available if you choose .NET Framework v3.5) for this purpose. Here is a simple tutorial on WCF services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx